# What's the difference between serial-port and serial tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Title says it all.

Both tags have pretty much just [serial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/serial) or [serial-port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) mentioned just once (!), and the tag appears.

Someone is kind enough to make an excerpt of both tags to separate [cal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide) from sand?

<sub>(I really hope that everybody knows this saying)</sub>

I'm not saying to nuke them (actually, serial... don't seems a useful tag for me), just to make things more... organized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"serial" on its own is too ambiguous to be a tag.  It should probably be ditched in favour of "serial-port".

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to make [serial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/serial) a synonym of [serial-port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/serial-port).

Comment: The problem with this is that sometimes it has "serial" as "ruby/serial/something" then is not recommendable to synonymize.

Comment: Those (hopefully) few cases would have to be weeded out :-)

Answer (score -1):

"serial-port" seems like, when used correctly, it would indicate the serial port itself, making it a hardware question not belonging on AskUbuntu. Wouldn't the correct tag be "serial-bus" or something? Ditching it for just "serial", as neon_overload suggests, would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: While something like [tag:serial-bus] might technically be a better tag for questions about accessing a ...serial port... in Ubuntu, I think [tag:serial-port] is much more likely to be correctly recognized and used. Also neon_overload is not suggesting ditching [tag:serial-port] for [tag:serial] but *the other way around*.

Answer (score -1):

`serial-port` tag should be used when you have questions about ports. Serial ports means that the data "streams" after each other and not at the same time as it is possible right now with parallel cables. So for example `universal serial bus` or short `USB` is a serial port.

while the tag `serial` can also be used if you have questions about serials in terms of keys or to do something in serial.

Sorry for my english, but I guess there is a difference between this tags.